# Batch script is adding funky characters when a command gets executed

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I have this script and when I try to execute it, a bunch of random symbols show up in the command prompt:

```
cd "X:\folder\subfolder"
svn update
pause
```

[image]

I have no idea what those symbols are called or how they got in front of the `cd` to try and figure out why this is happening.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

EDIT: After Techie's comments I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854360/visual-studio-inserts-invalid-characters-in-batch-files

Comment: What editor are you using to create the Batch file?  If you (re)create it in Notepad, does it still produce those extra characters?

Comment: I `Add New Item` in Visual Studio, created a `.txt` file and renamed it to `.bat`. I'll try that.

Comment: ...wtf. Creating a text file in Windows Explorer and then adding it to my VS Project that way fixes it.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Comment: I just tired the same thing you described (in VS2013 Pro) and it did the same thing.. added those characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when you save a Text file in Visual Studio it saves it in [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=UTF-8), including a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the beginning.

Since the command-line's default [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) isn't UTF-8, you see the characters.

You can set the command-line to support UTF-8 by issuing the command `chcp 65001`, but for compatibility sake you're best off ensuring your text/batch file is saved with standard ANSI encoding instead of UTF-8.

For that, see this other existing SU question: [Visual Studio 2010: Is it possible to force editor to use ANSI rather than UTF-8?](https://superuser.com/questions/134739/visual-studio-2010-is-it-possible-to-force-editor-to-use-ansi-rather-than-utf-8), which talks about the same thing you're seeing.

For more info on the subject, perhaps also check out this StackOverflow question: [Visual Studio inserts invalid characters in batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854360/visual-studio-inserts-invalid-characters-in-batch-files).

Comment: Yeah..  I think jadusty answer on [the mentioned StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854360/visual-studio-inserts-invalid-characters-in-batch-files) is the best way to manage these issues.

Comment: You write "when you save a Text file in Visual Studio it saves it in UTF-8 encoding, which includes a byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning."  <---You could be more specific here. Visual Studio saves it as UTF8 with BOM.  But there does exist a UTF 8 without the BOM